# List Item Timeout Issue

Tags: 2010, performance, list-item, time-out

On one of our production Sharepoint Sites we have a ListItem that will not load it's details. It simply times out and throws an exception with a GUID.  The Log file indicates that:

System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
08/25/2011 13:14:04.03  w3wp.exe (0x1DB4)   0x1184  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpm    High    Unable to execute query: Error 0x80131530   66c92e39-0443-40b0-bef8-d9d74e292fbd

I am asking for Read access to all databases on our Sharepoint server so that I can see how long the SQL command (shown in the logs) takes to execute.  It's an absolute massive query.

How does one go about troubleshooting a Listitem that is having SQL Server timeouts?

Comment: I'm not sure if this statistic is helpful or even meaningful, but the select query that is supposedly timing out took 1:57 seconds to execute and returned ~6700 rows

Comment: You can try to enable the developer dashboard. You should be able to see the query that is running and timing out.

Comment: I was able to see the query that is timing out from the Log file using UDLViewer.   I've also read where some engineers increase the SQL timeout to up to 5 minutes! This doesn't feel like the best solution to me

Comment: I've also been informed that a microsoft project document was attached to the listitem yesterday.  I'm attaching the same file in our test enviroment to see if I can duplicate the issue.  No luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Does the item have a it's own ACL's, i.e. it's security has been "decoupled" from the parent list?
- Does it have a lot of lookup columns?
- Is Project Server installed (or deinstalled) and is sharepoint assuming it should do some extra project server stuff it shouldn't?
- Are there any audiences assigned to the item?

An item level query will only grow this big if it needs to do some joins for say ACL's, lookups etc. I.e. the item references other stuff instead of having all it's data "self-contained".

Comment: Does the item have a it's own ACL's, i.e. it's security has been "decoupled" from the parent list? **Yes**  
Does it have a lot of lookup columns? **One or two**  
Is Project Server installed (or deinstalled) and is sharepoint assuming it should do some extra project server stuff it shouldn't? **No and No**  
Are there any audiences assigned to the item? **There are user fields that can contain multiple users / groups.  Does that answer this question?**

Comment: I found there are 24 user lookups. There are also 415 versions of this listitem. Could versioning be haunting us here?

Comment: Yes, defininately! SP will build a huge query (joins) to get all the ACL's and versions etc. Could u try and download the file, then reupload it using a different name (i.e. make it a "clean" version) in the same library?

Comment: It's actually a listitem.- not a file  So I guess I cannot.  I read where one guy recommended increasing the request length and timeout period. http://sharepointgauravgoyal.blogspot.com/2011/04/increase-upload-size-request-timeout.html  This seems far from ideal in my mind.  I'm going to look into version cleaup today. EG what would happen if I lowered the versioning from 1k to 250.